# Scrolling below the min value in NumberPicker

Tags: android, numberpicker

My NumberPicker is defined as follows:

```
<NumberPicker
 android:id="@+id/np"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:gravity="center" />
```

---

```
final NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.np);
    np.setMinValue(1);
    np.setMaxValue(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    np.setValue(3);
```

I would like the user to be able to select any integer number (no max bound):

[image]

When scrolling up above 1 (meaning below the min val) I'm getting to the max val, but can't go back anymore:

[image]

So I'm facing two issues:

First, I would like to be able to scroll back down.
Second, it would be best if I couldn't scroll above 1 in the first place. If any user got to the max val and couldn't scroll any more down, that would be just fine..

Comment: Well apparently this is some Android bug, as if I set 'setMaxValue(100);', there's no such issue. Guess I'll have to settle for that.

Comment: Did you try with np.setMaxValue(Integer.MAX_VALUE-1); ?